# Excel, covert row cell into comma separated list

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet having n number of rows with six columns
I need to insert all these rows into a database table.
So I want to convert each row cells into comma separated and marked by quote list.
Also if any cell is empty then its value should be marked as empty string('')

Example:
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zglDd.png)

Comment: Just export your sheet as a .csv file.

Comment: Or use `TEXTJOIN()` =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`=IF(A1>0,"'"&A1&"', ",""",")&IF(B1>0,"'"&B1&"', ",""",")&IF(C1>0,"'"&C1&"', ",""",")&IF(D1>0,"'"&D1&"', ",""",")&IF(E1>0,"'"&E1&"', ",""",")&IF(F1>0,"'"&F1&"'", """,")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXTJOIN with "do not skip empty cells" and use quote-comma-quote as the join. Prepend and append a single quote, and you're done:

`="'" & TEXTJOIN("','",FALSE,A1:F1) & "'"`